# Performing segue after animation takes long

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode6

I'm trying to perform a segue in the completion block of an animation in Swift. However, the segue takes a long time(about 10 seconds) to do and I'm not sure why. Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        imageViewAnimated.startAnimating()


        if label.center != CGPoint(x:50, y:10) {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.label.center = self.view.center

                }, completion: nil)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.label.alpha = 0.0

                }, completion: { finished in

                    self.poof.alpha = 1.0
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the new view loading a lot of data?

Comment: The new view is nothing but a text box and button, but the old view has a lot of large images being loaded into it.

Comment: Why are you transitioning away from the viewController as soon as it appears?

Comment: It's supposed to transition a few seconds after the view controller appears, once the animation is done.

Comment: Does the animation work right away?  Or does it take a long time to get to the animation?

Comment: The animation takes a few seconds to work, but not nearly as long as the segue.

Comment: Sounds like the view is taking a bit to load, then runs the animation, then performs the segue.  Also, the first animation is longer than the second, so it will wait before seguing.

Comment: Anything I can do to improve it or is it out of my control?

Comment: You could try to speed up the image loading by using compressed images or pre-loading.  That would be your best bet.

Comment: Okay I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: @BaileyMiller any chance you are using IOS emulator? or this is IOS phone?

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)

            imageViewAnimated.startAnimating()


            if label.center != CGPoint(x:50, y:10) {

                UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.label.center = self.view.center

                    }, completion: nil)

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.label.alpha = 0.0

                    }, completion: { finished in

                        self.poof.alpha = 1.0
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: nil)
                        })
                })
            }
        }
```